# How to retrieve to which remote and remote branch the current branch is corresponding to in Mercurial?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

To get the corresponding to the current branch name of remote and name of remote branch in Git the following command can be used:

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}
```

It returns something like:

```
<some-remote-name>/<some-remote-branch-name>
```

Where `<some-remote-name>` is the name of the remote and `<some-remote-branch-name>` is the name of the remote branch which the current branch tracks.

For example, it can be:

```
origin/master
```

How to do the same thing in Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial branches do not have Git semantics; a branch name in Mercurial is *not* a head and these concepts just don't really correspond.  Branch names in Mercurial are truly global and the name you use in *your* repository is the name that other Mercurial repositories will use in *their* repositories.<sup>1</sup>  Branch names in Git have an upstream setting, but branch names in Mercurial do not (they have no need for this concept).  The branch that a commit is made on, is the branch the commit will forever be on; it will never be on any other branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>The Convert extension allows the names to map back and forth to different strings across different Mercurial repositories, but the fundamental issues remain, here.